# Android TabListener: onTabSelected - add fragment to back stack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I use in my Android application a `TabListener` similar to this one: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

My `onTabSelected` implementation:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Fragment preInitFrag = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
    if (preInitFrag == null) {
        mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
    } else {
        ft.attach(preInitFrag);
    }
}
```

Every time a tab is selected, I want to add it to the back stack. How can I do this? Using the parameter `ft` with `ft.addToBackStack("test")`, it does not work. It throws a fatal exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
    Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.../...BaseActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    This FragmentTransaction is not allowed to be added to the back stack.
```

Comment: It is `addToBackStack(String name)` you should pass to it the name of your fragment class.

Comment: I do not understand your comment, sorry. How can I perform an ``addToBackStack`` inside the ``onTabSelected``callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ActionBar guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) that you linked to in your question has this to say about the back stack (In the "caution" section below the tab listener sample code):

> You also cannot add these fragment transactions to the back stack.

The guide doesn't explain why, but what you want is not supported. You'll have to keep tag history in some other way, or don't keep tab history at all.

Comment: Oh, I read this page more than 10 times, but this I did not see. So okay, I had to solve it in some other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create you own FragmentTrasaction inside the onTabChanged callback, and try commit();
Check the below link.

[FragmentTransaction is not allowed to be added to back stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231161/fragmenttransaction-is-not-allowed-to-be-added-to-back-stack/14389790#14389790)