# Android app closes when back button pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment, back-stack

I have the following activity which launches a fragment when the tab is selected:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TabListener {
    Fragment f = null;
.....

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        .....

        if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
            if (initalSync == true) {
                progress1.setVisibility(TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN);
            }
            f = new EventFragment();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("idx", tab.getPosition());
            f.setArguments(data);

        }
        if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
            progress1.setVisibility(TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN);
            f = new MapsFragment();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("idx", tab.getPosition());
            f.setArguments(data);

        }
        .....    
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f);

    }
```

When ever I press the phones back button on any of the fragments it closes my app. I know this is related to the backstack but every method I have tried fails.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: no error when running the app, its only when I press the back button and the entire app closes

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6es9y1o12wy02g/log.txt

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your fragments to the backstack if you don't want the activity to close by the time you press back, all you have to do is calling the following method:

```
ft.addToBackStack(null)
```

before you replace and commit your transaction.
This way the fragments injection you are using will be tracked down, and the back button will change to the previos fragment until reaching the first action and then it will close the app.

Regards!

Comment: I added that line just above the ft.replace statement and it crashes the app

Comment: you are not creating your own transaction are you? you are using the one that comes from the callback right?

Comment: yes, is this where the problem lies? if so how can I fix it?

Comment: look at the 3rd answer of this question, seems like exactly what you are trying to do is forbidden. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231161/fragmenttransaction-is-not-allowed-to-be-added-to-back-stack

Comment: so my back button is useless

Comment: not really, if you have an activity before that one in the backstack, you will be sent to that activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [addToBackstack(null)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29) on the Transaction to add the fragment to the backstack. Then the back button should revert to the previous fragment.

Comment: You need to call it after the replace call.