# Back Press on fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I am using sliding menu in my app and starts fragments from MainActivity 
i want to close application when back button is pressed.
what it is doing that it opens the activity when back button is pressed in last fragment but i want to exit the app when back button is pressed in last fragment. how can i do this.

this is my on create

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0057b3")));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    graphicUtil = new GraphicsUtil();

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    // My Feeds
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Private Feeds
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // My Profile
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // People and Groups
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Messages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // Favorites
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(5, -1)));
    // Credits
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(6, -1)));
    // Settings
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(7, -1)));
    // About this app
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(8, -1)));
    // Contact us
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(9, -1)));
    // Log Out
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons
            .getResourceId(10, -1)));

    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


    // open default fragment

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        displayView(0);
    }
}
```

this my display view method that opens the fragments

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        // fragment = new MyPublicPostsFragment();
        fragment = new MyFeedsFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new MyPrivatePostsFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new MyProfileFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new PeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new MessagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new FavouritesFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new CreditsFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        break;
    case 8:
        fragment = new AboutThisAppFragment();
        break;
    case 9:
        fragment = new ContactUsFragment();
        break;
    case 10:
        fragment = new LogOutFragment();
        store.setLoginStatus(null);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("Main Activity", "error in creating fragment");
    }}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this (some betters than others):

- Way 1: Perform a fragment transaction with a TAG string. That way in `onBackPressed()` on the MainActivity you can check with `findFragmentByTag` what the current fragment is, if is the fragment you want to exit, then exit, if not do nothing.
- Way 2: As your `displayView` method is using a switch you can store the integer position in your MainActivity, that way in `onBackPressed()` you can check what integer is, and therefore you can know what fragment is.
- Way 3: You can also create a variable called `mCurrentFragment` to store the current fragment, in `onBackPressed()` you can check with `instanceOf` what fragment is, and apply the same logic.
- Way 4: You can create a listener that the fragments must implement and when calling `onBackPressed`, then call the listener and do whatever you need to do.

If you need code examples tell me and I'll add it gladly.

**EDIT 1:**

Keep in mind that this is pseudocode, it may contain any typo or something, check it properly with the compiler.

In your MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   // Code... 

   private Fragment mCurrentFragment;

   // Code...

   private void displayView(int position) {
      switch (position) {
         case 0:
           mCurrentFragment = new MyFeedsFragment();
           break;
         // Substitute fragment for mCurrentFragment in the rest of the method...
   }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      if (mCurrentFragment instanceof LogOutFragment) {
        finish();
      } else {
         // Do whatever you want to do if necessary
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: Great! As I said before, if you need more help about this issue, comment here and I'll update the answer to add code or whatever you need! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove addToBackStack() from here: `.addToBackStack(null).commit();`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: how to detect back press in fragments

Comment: It's already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button)

Comment: that is for Activity but i want to get back press in fragments

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in your MainActivity().java

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;
    finish();
}
```

Comment: what it does is whenever i press back button it finishes the application, but i want is when a specific fragment is open and in that fragment when back is pressed only then application exits

Comment: go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101442/android-app-closes-when-back-button-pressed